# Not receiving device token in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

In my AppDelegate, I'm using the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method. But despite seeing the success message in my code below in the logs, I'm not seeing the device token get printed or saved into UserDefaults as written in the method.

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate  {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) {(success, error) in
      if success {
        print("Success in APNS registry")
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
          }
      } else {
        print("error \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error")")
      }
    }
    NetworkMonitor.shared.startMonitoring()
    return true
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    print("Token is \(tokenString)")
    userDefaults.set(tokenString, forKey: "deviceToken")
  }
}
```

I've tried a couple of times by deleting the app from my phone and installing again. Every time I accept the prompt, I see the success message but no token is printed. Before I was using Firebase GCM, but I'm now going down a different path and am no longer want to use it. I'm unsure if there's some config for that which I need to remove, there's nothing in the logs though saying I need to remove it.

Comment: There is no need for the async dispatch into the main queue. Also, obtaining the remote notification token is not linked to having notification permissions. The permission just means your app can show the notification. You can get the token to send notifications regardless.  I would recommend that you call `registerForRemoteNotifications` on launch, outside of the notification permission request and also implement the [`didFail`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622962-application) delegate method.

Comment: Also, why are you saving the token in `UserDefaults`?  You need to send the token to your server.

Comment: Thank you, I'll implement that delegate method. Where else can I get the device token? Searching the internet, I only see references to `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications`, which is why I saved the token to `UserDefaults` so I could later send it to the server. I was getting an issue when calling `registerForRemoteNotifications` because it wasn't on the main thread.

Comment: That is the right way to get the token.  You should simply call `registerForRemoteNotifications` in `didFinishLaunching` regardless of whether you have notification permission or not.

Answer (score 1):

I finally realized that it is because of the [method swizzling done by Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in) (even though I don't use Cloud Messaging). In order to resolve this, you should add

```
FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = NO (boolean)
```

in your Info.plist file.